# Filling a 3d object that was sliced

Tags: modeling

Trying to fill this and create a flat backing so I can mount on a project. I bought this design and sliced in half. I've tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F</kbd> (*Fill* + *Grid fill*). Just trying to make a back basically.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the slice is at one height you can take a cube and difference bool it with the object just a slit bit, so they are interecting a bit.
Before the slicing:

[image]

Let them overlap just a bit, so you dont loose any detail

[image]

After boolean:

[image]